# How can I view IP address from a serial monitor on my arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I am working with an esp8266 WiFi module and I can't view my IP address on my serial monitor. I am connected to a hotspot but the serial monitor won't display the IP address. Please I need help....

Comment: Take a look at https://circuits4you.com/2017/12/31/esp8266-get-ip-address. If it does not work we would need more details to help.

Comment: I am using the serial monitor to get the IP address not through the router as explained in the link above.. I still can't get the IP address pls..

Comment: The sketch in the link opens the WIFI connection (which is a prerequisite to have an IP address), then prints the IP to the serial monitor (Serial.println, Line 30) so it does exacly what you ask for. Please show what you are doing otherwise there is no way to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok. But pls I have already uploaded a sketch for the project I am working on. How can I delete it before upload the one on the link.... I am using arduino IDE

Comment: Just upload the new sketch, the old one will be overwritten. You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before your next question.

Comment: Thanks Christoph it worked.... I'll definitely adjust on how to ask.. Just that am new here.... Thanks once more..

Comment: Glad to hear, welcome to the community!